# How do I generate an alert on Debian if a redunant PSU dies?

Tags: debian, intel

I have received some Intel servers with redundant power supplies - Intel S1200v3RP. We have Debian installed on them.

Looking on Intel's site, we cannot find any downloads for Debian, but we see some for RedHat and SLES.

Is there a way to monitor the redundant power supplies to ensure we get an alert if one dies?

Comment: If your PSUs are PMBus-compliant, you can probably use the Linux Hardware monitoring driver for PMBus devices.

Comment: I'm not sure, they have a signal cable going to the motherboard though